# How to get the original size of screenshots using iOS Simulator in Xcode 7 when scaling down

Tags: xcode, xcode7, simulator

In Xcode 7.1 Simulator, when using `⌘+s` to save screenshot to desktop, it saves the actual size of the simulator. For example, iPhone 6 Plus `100%` scale simulator save screenshots as `1242 x 2208`; `25%` scale simulator save screenshots as `310 x 552`.

Is there a way to make the simulator scale to `25%` but still get original size of `1242 x 2208`? The `100%` simulator is just too huge on a 13" screen.

It used to save as original size regardless scale level, but in Xcode 7.1 it's no longer the case.

Comment: "The 100% simulator is just too huge on a 13" screen" Who cares? Just make it 100% for the one moment where you need to take the screen shot; then go back to 25%.

Comment: This answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/34003920/701926 will explain how to stop it saving out the scaled images so you don't have to mess around un-scaling it for each screenshot.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

[image]

Uncheck "Optimize Rendering for Window Scale" option from "Debug" menu, if you want to save screenshot of actual device size  from iOS simulator.

Happy Programming!!

Comment: That menu does not seem to exist anymore

Comment: @FranckJeannin did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

@SamSol's answer may work for earlier versions of Xcode, but the debug window does not appear to be present in Xcode 11+.

Instead, I followed [this suggestion](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/109503) from the Apple Developer forum:

1. In the Simulator, go to Edit -> Copy Screen (^⌘C)
2. Open Preview and paste as a new image (⌘N)
3. Save the resulting image (⌘S)

The saved output image should have the desired resolution to be included on the Apple App Store.

Comment: it does not work for me :( size is always too small, does not matter if I copy screen, save screen, or even if I take a screen on my actual iPhone. Edit: Was a different problem. Was trying to upload 4,7" screenshot for the 5,5" display

Answer (score -2):

- To take a screenshot of the iOS, watchOS, or tvOS device and save it to your Mac Clipboard

> choose Edit  > Copy Screen.

- To save a screenshot of the iOS, watchOS, or tvOS device and of the external display as files

> choose File  > Save Screen Shot.

A screenshot of each open simulated device is saved to the desktop of your Mac.

Comment: The question indicates he knows how to do this - what he wants is for the simulator to not scale down the image when running the simulator at != 100%. Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/34003920/701926 explains how.