# iPhone simulator screenshot is not in proper dimension

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

What I want to do is to upload screenshot of app on iTunes connect, so I take the screenshot from the simulator for all iPhone devices.

When I tried to upload these screenshots on iTunes connect, I got the error `The dimensions of one or more screenshots are wrong`.

so I verify the dimension of each screenshot which are as follows

- iPhone 4 -> 320 x 480
- iPhone 5 -> 320 x 568
- iPhone 6 -> 375 x 667
- iPhone 6+ -> 621 x 1104

This dimensions should be

- iPhone 4 -> 640 x 960
- iPhone 5 -> 640 x 1136
- iPhone 6 -> 750 x 1334
- iPhone 6+ -> 1242 x 2208

so the question is why the simulator screenshot coming in @1x not @2x.

I am using Xcode 7.1.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: i am using xcode 7.0.1 and it is taking the screenshots in correct dimension i.e. for iphone 6 it is 750x1334

Comment: How are you taking the screen shots?

Comment: from simulator by using command+s

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to scale simulator down, say 50%, and still get screenshots in proper dimensions, disable "optimize rendering for window scale" in debug menu of simulator. [image]

Comment: Thank you, this is much better than having to scale the simulator every time and I also think it renders better with the setting turned off.

Answer (score 4):

Set your simulator scale 100%, then using cmd+s. I tested, it worked.

[image]

Comment: I was also getting the same issue, it worked for me with 5,6,6+ but there is still some issue with the iphone 4.

Comment: Did you try like i said above? it's still fine for me.

Comment: It worked after disabling the optimize rendering for window scale.