# simulator 100% scale screen capture in Xcode 9.1 (Simulator 10.0)

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

I want to take 100% scale screen shot of my simulator.
However recently simulator was updated and I can't change its scale to 100%.

Could you please tell me how to capture 100% scale screenshot on my simulator?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765160/how-to-get-the-original-size-of-screenshots-using-ios-simulator-in-xcode-7-when

Comment: I will check right row

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33765160/how-to-get-the-original-size-of-screenshots-using-ios-simulator-in-xcode-7-when worked.

Comment: I didn't know that I can capture 100% scale screenshot without making my simulator 100% scale. Anyways, [Simulator] -> [Debug] -> Uncheck [Optimize rendering for Window Scale] worked!